# create a plot from two dataframe with two y -axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want a plot with two y-axes from two different data frame in one plot.

So far I tried to change the one data frame two y-axes version but I failed.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close("all")
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x1": [1,2 ,3 ,4 ],
                   "y1_1": [555,525,532,585], 
                   "y1_2": [50,48,49,51]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x2": [1, 2, 3,4],
                   "y2_1": [557,522,575,590], 
                   "y2_2": [47,49,50,53]})
ax1 = df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_1", legend=False)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
ax3 = df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_1", legend=False)
ax4 = ax1.twinx()
df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_2", ax=ax4, legend=False, color="r")
plt.grid(True) 
ax1.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

below this is what I want.
[image]
So far I have two plots but I want just everything in one plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
ax1 = df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_1", legend=False)
ax2=ax1.twinx()
df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_1", ax=ax1, legend=False)
df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
```

which gives:

[image]

Or, you can predefine `ax1` and `ax2`, then pass them to `plot` functions:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2=ax1.twinx()

df1.plot(x="x1", y= ["y1_1"], ax=ax1, legend=False)
df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_1", ax=ax1, legend=False)
df2.plot(x="x2", y="y2_2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nice solution. Just one question why does have the grid only horizontally lines?

Comment: That just the default settings of my pyplot.

Comment: Ok, but I get the same result should not I get a different result or is my default the same as yours?

Comment: That's because you have `plt.grid(True)`, remove it or change it it `plt.grid(False)`.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it can not work with element from a list  because I got AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'twinx'

Comment: is your `ax1 = df1.plot(x="x1", y="y1_1", legend=False)`?

Comment: I have to check if it is the CSV file, from which I created the dataframe from